# Tabs and content into Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tabs like in this example:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">me</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">you</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 9</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I want to turn all of it into array's : me=>1,2,3,4,5  you=>5,6,7,8,9 any ideas? Thought maybe sortable1< li.index and give every li id but how to connect it with tab? Little help would be nice.

Comment: You want `1, 2, ...` or `Item 1, Item 2, ...`?

Comment: I am not clear what this sentence means:  "sortable1< li.index and give every li id".  And connect it with tab how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var obj = {};

$('#tabs > ul li a').each(function(i,ele) {
    obj[$(ele).text()] = $.map($('li', $(ele).attr('href')), function(k, i) {
        return $(k).text();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eC5Tj/4/)

Comment: +1 beautiful. i like how this answer makes the least assumptions. the only assumption is on the structure. which is easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
var meid = $("#tabs a:contains(me)").attr("href");
var youid = $("#tabs a:contains(you)").attr("href");

var me = $("li", $(meid)).map(function() { return $(this).text() });
var you = $("li", $(youid)).map(function() { return $(this).text() });
```

Answer (score 0):

The guys provided much more succinct answers. I didn't use $.map but here's what I wrote (might be useful for someone):

```
var tabs = $("#tabs");
var firstUL = tabs.first("ul");
var akeys = firstUL.find("a");

var valueDivs = tabs.children("div");

var dictionary = {};

$.each(akeys, function(index, value) {
    var key = $(value).text();
    dictionary[key]  = $(valueDivs[index]).find("li");
});

//now dictionary contains all the <li> elements organized by the names in the first ul
//the beauty of JavaScript's dynamic features:
alert($(dictionary.me[0]).text()); //this will show Item 1
alert($(dictionary["you"][4]).text()); //this will show Item 9
```